# tkinter change border color on button

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I have a tkinter program with a button:

```
button = tk.Button(text="Next", width=10, height=1, borderwidth=1, relief=tk.SOLID, highlightbackground="blue")
```

However the blue border doesn't seem to appear using `highlightbackground`.

I am trying to make this look like the windows buttons:

[image: Windows 7 OK Button]

Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Comment: is this on windows?

Comment: @BryanOakley yes

Comment: Hi, do you know the answer?

Comment: @SeakyLone Sorry I don't and haven't used `tkinter` in a long time